# div in the middle of another

Tags: css, html, margin

I want to place a `<div>` into another and want to center it. 
My way is this:

```
<div id="redthing">
<div id="whitebox" >
</div>
</div>
```

The .css - code is the following:

```
#redthing {
margin-top: 2px;
background-color: #f00d28;
height: 250px;
}

#whitebox {
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 height: 10px;
 width: 400px;
 background-color: white;
 border:5px solid #000;
}
```

Like you can see, padding and margin does not work to center it in the middle of the page(that means that there is the same place between the `whitebox` and the top and the bottom of the `redbox`. 
Please help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let's take a look at what you have. Every line in this drawing represents 10px in height:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃10px margin top        ┃
┃┌─────────────────────┐┃
┃│20px padding top     │┃
┃│padding continues    │┃
┃│10px height          │┃
┃└─────────────────────┘┃
┃                       ┃
┊  lots of empty space  ┊
┃                       ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

Explain how that's supposed to work?

You either need to make sure your padding and margin add up to the correct amount, or use this:

```
/* add this to the container */
position: relative;

/* add this to the inner box */
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -Xpx;
/* where X is half the offsetHeight of the box - ie. (height+padding+border)/2 */
```

Comment: @Fresheyeball Kindly do not edit my answer if you're just going to ░▒▓ up the box drawing.

Comment: @Kolink sorry, I thought the breakage of the lines was in error. My bad.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Oh, I see what happened. The "monospace" font... isn't monospace. So I had it lined up on my browser, but yours obviously renders fonts slightly differently.

Comment: @Kolink weeeiiirrd! What browser and OS are you?

Comment: IE9 on Win7, but I tested in Chrome on same computer and found out that your edit did indeed line up.